# Display a medium sized dataset from one table in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

For an app I am creating I am looking for the correct way to display a medium sized records set (around 130 records, with about 13 columns). The data is now in a sqlite database, which I want to use to display in a `UITableView`. With this quantity of records and columns I think an array is way too memory intensive?

From looking around (and previous experiences) I think I best go for Core Data and use an `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I am not sure about this. There is no need for the data to be changed or added. So using this might be overkill?

If this is the way to go though, I would love to know what components to use, as I cannot really find an answer to this sort of question. 
If this is not the way to go, please point me in the right direction in which I should go.

Comment: In the end I ended up using `Core Data` as this seemed like the best solution for this kind of problem. I had already tried working with `Core Data` before, so the learning curve was a little less steep ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is a good match. It can also be used with sqlite as a datastore however you would probably have to reimport your data. The `NSFetchedResultsController` makes it fairly easy to use a core data collection as a datasource for the table-view. The modeling tools in XCode make it also pretty convenient to create your data structure and creating the `NSManagedObject` subclasses from it. I would also take into consideration that you might want to extend your dataset or structure in the future and core data has battle tested facilities to assist you with these tasks.

Comment: Thanks, will try to fix it in this way as I also think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little trick, you needn't select all data from this table and transform into an array, just select data like this:

```
SELECT `recordid` FROM `yourtable`;
```

in the delegate method "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:", you can now load all rest data from this record:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE `recordid` = [indexPath row];
```

If your database records is still growing, you can fetch your data by paging query:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourtable` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you need. In particular, if you have to release the application in a day or so, well, refactoring to Core Data would be an obstacle. It has a very steep learning curve so it cannot be digested in a day. On the contrary if you have more time to spend, yes go with Core Data and reuse the know-how in the future.

So, stick with two options here. Stay with plain SQL or just migrate to Core Data. Well, if you have chosen the second, the master component you need is the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

This class works in combination with `UITableView` offering a lot of functionalities. One of the most important is to maintain a small memory footprint. In fact, if you work with batch sizes you can take advantage of lazy loading mechanism. Say for example, you want a batch of 20 items. The `NSFetchedResultsController` will load the first 20 items, if you scroll down, it will load other 20 and so on.

Comment: If you will be using pure SQLite and query and load data inside cellForIndexPath method - it also will be effectively "lazy" and will not burden memory with unnecessary data.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem will be not how to organize your internal data structures, but how effectively present 13 columns of to the user, taking into account very little screen real estate you have on iPhone. Have you thought about that?

There are few options here

- you can present just some kind of brief information into main table view and for each cell have detail view with the rest of the information
- you can dynamically generate bunch of labels inside each cell and populate them with your data, but now you're really facing space limitation, since you probably won't fit that much of a data in one row. And you also need to create custom headers in your table view (if you need to show header)
- or you can invent something else. When I had to deal with very similar issue I went and implemented something similar to Excel "freeze columns" functionality - where header columns is fixed and stays on the screen always and all data columns can be scrolled horizontally and basically go underneath the header. See screenshot attached (note scroll bars around columns with stat data):

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but the OP didn't ask for this.

Comment: @flexaddicted: I always try to think and encourage people asking questions "what are you trying to achieve?". Because even though the original question might be different - reasons for it's asking and background of the problem might be very important and might lead to a solution OP wasn't even thinking about.

Comment: Yes but here you suppose that all 13 columns will be displayed within the UI. The OP describes only his db structure and not what he wants to display...

Comment: Yet the title of the question state "Display a medium sized dataset from one table in UITableView".

Comment: In the end I did not specifically ask for this information (only in title indeed), but it is definitely something I had not yet thought trough. So this information is definitely useful to me! So thanks.
I had another option by the way, and that was to display only the most important data in portrait, and all data in landscape mode.

Comment: @Hugo - I tried that too (showing different data in different orientations).